# flask route variables 404 not found

Tags: python-2.7, .htaccess, asp.net-web-api, flask, cgi

I have been trying to get a simple web api to run on my shared hosting environment through 1and1.

I have setup this path ~/myapp/api where i put all my python scripts.
This is the one I can't get to work (test.py):

the problem is with the last route. It will only work if I create the directory "tables." otherwise it throws a not found error.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/myapp/')
def api_base():
  return "/myapp"

@app.route('/myapp/api/')
def api_base_full():
  return "/myapp/api"

@app.route('/myapp/api/table/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def api_routes_table():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return getAllTableItems()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return insertNewTableItem()
```

.htaccess in ~ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*)$ /myapp/api/cgitester.py/betabank/$1 [L]
```

cgiteseter.py:

```
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from test import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

I have a feeling the problem is with my .htaccess file cause I don't really know what i'm doing in there. I can't figure out how to fix this looking at flask documentation and stackoverflow posts. thanks for any help

what i'm trying to do is create a web api so that when I make GET calls to www.example.com/myapp/api/table it returns json of my database. Then www.example.com/myapp/api/table/3 will return table row 3. RIght now i just want it to print some text so I know the right function is getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out that my .htaccess file had a line in it from wordpress that was causing all the problems.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

after commenting out that line at the bottom it worked fine.

I just found this on an Oracle website:

A Rule to Match Any Address

> The special pattern "." (a single period) matches any host/domain
>   specification if no other rule matches and the host/domain
>   specification cannot be found anywhere in the channel table. In other
>   words, the "." rule is used as a last resort when address rewriting
>   would fail otherwise.